# WordPress directs me to another page on localhost

Tags: wordpress, redirect, moodle

I have installed Moodle 3.4 first, then I installed WordPress. I installed MySQL and PHP and followed the corresponding steps. Login to localhost / WordPress to continue configuring WordPress but it sent me to the Moodle page. The following is the file config.php of Moodle:

```
var/www/html/moodle/config.php
```

Its content:

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'mysqli';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';
$CFG->dbname    = 'moodle';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'user';
$CFG->dbpass    = 'pass';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbsocket' => '',
  'dbcollation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://localhost';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/var/www/html/moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';

$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;

require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/setup.php');

// There is no php closing tag in this file,
// it is intentional because it prevents trailing whitespace problems!
```

The installation of WordPress is in:

```
var/www/html/wordpress
```

This is the only thing I have modified in the file wp-config.php. Just changing my data.

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress_asesorias');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'wordpressuser');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');


/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

[URL in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J5MG.jpg)

Something must be generating conflict but I do not know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you `$CFG->wwwroot` moodle variable. Change this to `'localhost/moodle'` if you webserver is pointing to `/var/www/html`.
Alternatively, modify you hosts file (`/etc/hosts` for linux, `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` for windows) and set an alternative hostname to localhost, then change `$CFG->wwwroot` var with this value.

Comment: thanks for responds but still not working. Change $ CFG-> wwwroot to 'http://localhost/moodle' and add 127.0.0.1 project.example.com to etc/hosts and throw me the following error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: If you change you hosts file, set this value in $CFG->wwwroot = 'project.example.com'; not localhost. Make sure you webserver point to the correct directory